# Flask get csrf_token for Locust load testing

Tags: python, flask, locust

I want to implement to load testing with locust with my remote server, but I don't want to disabled csrf feature, how can I get csrf_token or by pass it

```
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def login(self):
        self.client.get("/securities/login") 
        token = "how to get it" 
        self.client.post("/securities/login",{"username":"test", 
                                              "password":"123",
                                              "csrf_token":token})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to find a token

```
import re
class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    @task(1)
    def login(self):
        result = self.client.get("/securities/login") 
        token = re.search(r'[0-9]{10}##[a-z0-9]{40}',result.text).group(0)
        print token
```

and one other way beside re(RegularExpression) is to use PyQuery to get token key from html form element.

Answer (score 0):

```
  result = self.client.get("/securities/login") 
  token = result.cookies['_csrf_token'] # i think this is the name anyway you could always print result.cookies to find out
```

at least i think ... I know this works in djanjo

with flask it may require a little more work ... see this gist https://gist.github.com/singingwolfboy/2fca1de64950d5dfed72

Comment: cookies['_csrf_token'] and cookies['csrf_token'] is not work

Comment: did you try printing result.cookies?

Comment: Cookies object looks difficult to see 
 
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie sessio
n=eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjp7IiBiIjoiTnpSa05HVmtORGd6TVdZellXVTFNVFk1WWpoaE9EVTVOelZoWl
dNME1XUTBObU01WkRkaVpBPT0ifX0.C63HBw.M8t5dyUS4d1v803_4EZ7nHwXCRo for exmaple.com/>]>

Answer (score 0):

If you use Flask_WTF, you can get the `csrf token` like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'random string'

class HelloForm(FlaskForm):
    # ...

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = HelloForm()
    token = form.csrf_token.data
```

Instead, you can also generate a token by yourself:

```
from hashlib import md5

def generate_csrf_token():
    token = md5(app.secret_key).hexdigest()
    return token
```